# Import classes from a distinct project which have same package name

Tags: java, class, gradle, import, package

I'm pretty sure the answer is somewhere but I didn't find it.
I have two separate projects which have same package name. I want to access from one project to a class of the other project (very simple).

**Project 1 :**

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'project1'
```

build.gradle

```
group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

User.java

```
package com.example.domain;

public class User {
    // ...
}
```

**Project 2 :**

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name=project2
```

build.gradle

```
group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
    compile "com.example:project1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

Group.java

```
package com.example.domain;

import com.example.domain.User;

public class Group{
    // ...
}
```

My question is: do I have to change package name (maybe com.example.**project1** and com.example.**project2**) or there is another way?

Remind: there are not subprojects from a main project.

Comment: I think this is one of the things package names were made for. If that were me, I would definitely want to change my package names in the direction you suggest yourself, even if another solution could be found for the concrete problem.

Comment: Yes, I think is the better way. Thank you for you advice.